# Function & array [Getting Max Number]

Tags: c++, arrays, function

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;


int getMax(numbers[], int size){
    int max = numbers[0];
    for(i=1; i<size; i++){
        if(numbers[i] > max)
        max = numbers[i];
    }
    return max;
}


int main(){
    
    int numbers[6] = {31,23,45,6,7,-2};
    cout << getMax(numbers, 6) << endl;
    
    
    return 0;
}
```

I can't seem to get the max number that I wanted from this code. And this is also my first time using stack overflow, so if there isn't enough information. Please spare me :)

I am not sure if tried enough soultions to slove this problem. I just wanted to see how stack overflow worked and whether I will get my question answered. :)

Comment: This code won't compile. Are you asking about that? Or are you saying you have a different program similar to this that does compile, but doesn't work as expected? Apart from syntax errors, your logic looks fine.

Comment: For reference: [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) contains useful information about upping your chances to get specific answers. In this case, the question doesn't make sense. You imply that you have a program that isn't running properly, but then you show a program that cannot even get to the stage of running because it cannot be compiled. If you have compilation errors, get in the habit of reading them and if you don't understand the message then include it with your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only thing I see wrong with this program are syntax errors. Compiling yields this:

```
error: 'numbers' was not declared in this scope
    6 | int getMax(numbers[], int size){
      |            ^~~~~~~
```

That's because you forgot to specify the *type* of the variable `numbers`. It is an integer array. You can fix this by writing:

```
int getMax(int numbers[], int size)
```

Similarly, you forgot to define `i` in the loop. Write this:

```
for(int i=1; i<size; i++)
```

Get in the habit of reading the compiler's error messages. They are important, and they are trying to tell you what's wrong. Always read the first error. Subsequent errors may be confusing, due to the flow-on effect of earlier errors.